# memtester error when testing two RAM memory cards together but successful test on each one

Tags: ubuntu, ram

I have bought a new 8GB memory ram with the same part number as the one my computer already has. After mounting the new memory, I see that Ubuntu has detected it and that the system has 16 GB of RAM. The bad part is that when I run `memtester 5G 2` I get lots of errors in all comparisons (random value, xor, sub, div....). However, when I leave only one of the 8GB RAM memory cards the `memtester 5G 2` returns ok for all fields and for both cards (obviously tested with only one at a time mounted in the pc). Why do you think this is happening? Is it just that one is older and too different than the other one? Both have the same Samsung part number but bought about 6 years apart. Do you think this will be fixed if I buy another 8GB of the new one?

**Update**
I have tried, as mentioned in the commentes, if the problem was the slot by running the same tests that were successfull for each RAM in the slot 1 but in slot 2. These test failed for both RAMs in slot 2 (when slot 1 was empty). I have decided to buy a 16GB RAM and mount it in slot 1. Tahnks for all your help!

Comment: It's believed that you shouldn't mix memory modules and as for errors, they could be explained either by the fact that they are now working in dual channel mode or they are working with suboptimal incompible settings

Comment: So you think I should buy a second one of the new 8GB RAM to replace the old one and have two of the new ones?

Comment: This could work. As for testing RAM I prefer memtest86: https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm

Comment: Could it not also be an issue with the second RAM slot on the motherboard? Do you have a pair of other RAM sticks to experiment with? The second slot has been unused for 6 years?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov but if they have the same part number, then they are the same thing, right? I don't see why age would be relevant, they're still the same hardware aren't they?

Comment: @ibuprofen yes, unused the second slot for 6 years.

Comment: @terdon maybe you're right in which case I've no idea. This could be a motherboard/CPU fault then or bad timings/IMC voltage.

Comment: @terdon I cannot asure they have the exact same xips, in fact, both rams look slightly different although the label (sticker) have the same number

Comment: @apalomer Try raising your IMC voltage by a very small amount and retest. E.g. if it's set to 1.4V try 1.41V or ever 1.42V.

Comment: Thought was that slot 2 could simply be dirty, causing some minimal bad connectivity, or in worst case malfunctioning for other reasons. Have you tried to rinse it? Did you blow out dust etc. before use? Also, if you have another pair that fist laying around check if they show the same symptoms (though could give false negative / positive).

Comment: If you run "normal" programs on 16GB do you get any problems? That memtester is doing a stress test.

Comment: @JeremyBoden that's the thing. I increased the ram because when compiling a qt application (with big resources like pdfs, images...) the computer was running out of memory and the compiler was stopped (something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52171430/4179302). After increasing the memory, the pc does not run out of memory, but at the same point the compiler produces an `internal compiler error: Segmentation fault`. That's why I tested the RAM to check if there was some error there....

Comment: I have updated the question with my final decission. Thanks for the help!